# Set attributes from a custom LoginHandler

Tags: java, shibboleth

I developed a LoginHandler for Shibboleth and I need to set some attributes so Shibboleth can put them on a SAMLResponse.

I am being able only to set the PrincipalName, using `HttpServletRequest.setAttribute(LoginHandler.PRINCIPAL_NAME_KEY, value)`, but I can not set other attributes that the SP needs (like uid, NameID).

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are seeking a solution for this, I just figured out that I need to create a Data Connector Extension, as in [this url](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPDevExtDataCtr)

Comment: Yes, a login handler doesn't set any attributes except the principal name, typically.